# passing real IP address from one nginx instance to another and writing it in the logs

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, log-files

Moving  a request to my internal nginx server I add to the call:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
```

when I try to print this value in the log the internal nginx the container crashes:

```
log_format verbose ' Real: $X-Real-IP ';
```

What am I doing wrong? (I also tried with "" around the variable, it didn't help.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server receives `X-Real-IP` as one of the headers in the HTTP request. Nginx makes each of the request header values available as a variable.

The variable name for http request header values begins with `$http_`. The header name is converted to lowercase, and each hyphen is replaced with an underscore.

For example `X-Real-IP` is available as `$http_x_real_ip`

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_) for details.

Answer (score 2):

One can use `ngx_http_realip_module` to make nginx use IP address in headers as the source IP everywhere inside nginx.

It is configured as follows:

```
set_real_ip_from 192.168.1.1 # IP address of the external nginx
real_ip_header X-Real-IP;
```

By using this module, there is no need to define own log formats, nginx outputs the real client IP in log files and all other places as the source IP address.